# How to suppress warnings when using include_tasks with non-existing directory?

Tags: ansible

Given the following playbook (using Ansible 2.4.3):

```
- name: foo
  hosts: foo
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - include_tasks: "{{item}}"
    with_fileglob: "foodir/*.yml"
```

Ansible prints a warning when the `foodir` directory does not exist.

```
TASK [include_tasks] ****************************
 [WARNING]: Unable to find 'foodir' in expected paths.
```

Even when adding `when: false` this warning gets printed, so even when checking for the existence of the directory, it would get printed.

How to suppress this warning?

(Obviously it would be an easy workaround just to ensure the directory exists before including the tasks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning is generated by `fileglob` lookup plugin (by `find_file_in_search_path` of `LookupBase` to be more precise). So it's happen before you hit any `when` statement.

So you either check for path existence and don't try to run `with_fileglob` (by separating it into another file, I guess).

Or patch plugin [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.4.3.0-1/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/fileglob.py#L58) to set `ignore_missing=True`.